# Python subprocess stdout does not read

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe, stdout

I am trying to run gnuplot via python.

I can send and run commands but cannot read the warnings or error messages from application. It just waits at here: "self.proc.stdout.readline()".

Here is my entire code:

```
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen

import fcntl, os

class Gnuplot:
    def __init__(self, debug=True):
        self.debug = debug
        if self.debug:
            print 'Initializing ...\n' 

        self.proc = Popen(['gnuplot','-persist'],stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)  
        fcntl.fcntl(self.proc.stderr.fileno(), fcntl.F_SETFL, os.O_NONBLOCK)

    def communicate(self, cin='\n'):
        self.proc.stdin.write(cin+'\n')
        cout, cerr = '', ''
        print "lol"
        if self.proc.stdout:
            cout = self.proc.stdout.readline()
            self.proc.stdout.close()
            print cout
        elif self.proc.stderr:
            cerr = self.proc.stderr.read()
            self.proc.stderr.close()
            print cerr


if __name__ == '__main__':
    g = Gnuplot()   
    g.communicate("set parameter\n")
    g.communicate("plot sin(x)\n")
```

It just waits at here:

```
cout = self.proc.stdout.readline()
```

Answer (score 1):

Warnings and errors generally output on the standard error stream rather than standard output (this stops results getting mixed up with warning messages, for example). Because you are reading from `stdout` first, and no output is given, you are not getting to the part where you read from `stderr`.

Note, that [`subprocess` recommends against accessing the streams directly](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stderr):

> Warning: Use communicate() rather than .stdin.write, .stdout.read or
>   .stderr.read to avoid deadlocks due to any of the other OS pipe
>   buffers filling up and blocking the child process.

You probably want to use [`process.communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) as suggested. This gives you a tuple of `stdout_data, stderr_data`, so just grab the second to get your warnings and errors. This sidesteps the issue of having to deal with reading the output manually, and problems like this.